# ${X_0} \in {\mathbb{C}^n},\forall Y \in {\mathbb{C}^n}\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? $ there is unitary matrix $U$, such that $UX_0=Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X_0\in{\mathbb{C}^n}$ .

Is this true that, for any  $Y\in{\mathbb{C}^n}$  there is   unitary matrix $U\in{M_n}$, such that $UX_0=Y$?

Comment: It's true only if they have the same length.

Comment: @John Ma - Why?

Comment: $X_0=1,Y=2\Rightarrow U=2\,\,$that is not unitary.

Comment: @A.F.23 - Now let they have the same lengh, why does this question is hold?

Answer (score 2):

I can't prove that but maybe this help:
$$U=\left[[u_1],[u_2],...,[u_n]\right]\,\, \text{where}\,\, B=\{u_i\colon 1\leq i\leq n\}\,\,\text{is an orthonormal base for}\,\,{\Bbb C}^n\\
X=[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]^T\,\,,\,\,Y=[y_1,y_2,...,y_n]^T\\UX=x_1u_1+x_2u_2+...+x_nu_n=Y$$
It means that B is an orthonormal base such that matrix representation of Y relative to it is X. You know relation between two bases and transformation matrix formula, use that maybe you can solve this equation for U.

Answer (score 1):

This holds if and only if $X_0$ and $Y$ have the same dimensions and $X_0^* X_0 = Y^* Y$:

1. If $U X_0 = Y$, then $Y^* Y = (UX_0)^* (UX_0) = X_0^* U^* U X = X_0^* X$.
2. If $X_0^* X_0 = Y^* Y$, then there exist the following singular decompositions of $X_0$ and $Y$: $X_0 = U_X \Sigma V$ and $Y = U_Y \Sigma V$. Define $U = U_Y U_X^*$.